# JavaScript p5 make picture move that spawns at random location

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making a game using JavaScript and the p5 library. I have a function `enemy1_spawn` that takes an argument of how many enemies I need. My enemy spawns at a random location and I need it to move from left to right across the screen(I'll set other required conditions later). My problem is that the program keeps reloading so the enemy picture just keeps spawning and doesn't move at all.

I'm attaching my javaScript code. The code in comments are some of the attempts I made to make it work, although I have tried other methods.

```
var enemy_position = [];
var positiony = 100;

function preload() {
    backgroundImg = loadImage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/extra/map1.png");
    moneyImg = loadImage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/extra/dollar.png");
    livesImg = loadImage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/extra/lives.png");
    enemy1 = loadImage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/enemies/enemy1.png");

}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 600);
    livesImg.resize(40, 40);


}

function draw() {

    background(60, 238, 161);
    image(backgroundImg,0,0);
    image(moneyImg, 790, 0);
    image(livesImg, 805, 60);
    ShowTowers();
    enemy1_spawn(1);

}

function ShowTowers(){
    let firetowerbase_button;
    var button_size = {
        width: 120,
        height: 40
    }

    textSize(28);
    let textwidth;
    textwidth = textWidth("Towers");

    text("Towers", 800 + textwidth/2, 150);
    firetowerbase_button = createButton('Fire Tower');
    firetowerbase_button.size(button_size.width, button_size.height);
    firetowerbase_button.position(780 + button_size.width/2, 180);
}

function enemy1_spawn(number_of_enemies){
    var position = {
        // x: random(10, 100),
        x: 0,
        y: 100
    }
    // var positionx = 0;

    // for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
    // image(enemy1, position.x, position.y + i*80);
    // }
        // image(enemy1, position.x, position.y);
    for (var i = 0; i < number_of_enemies; i++) {
        var positionx = random(-100, 0);
        enemy_position.push([positionx, positiony]);
        // console.log(enemy_position[i]);
    }

    // for(var j = 0; j<enemy_position.length; j++){
    //  image(enemy1, enemy_position[j][0], enemy_position[j][1]);
    //  enemy_position[j][0]--;
    // }
    
        for(j = 0; j<enemy_position.length; j++){
            image(enemy1, enemy_position[j][0], enemy_position[j][1]);

    }
}
```

---

### Updates

---

I tried to implement this class however, it doesn't seem to be working, it gives me an error saying that random has to be defined in `setup`, but then I'm not sure how to use it here if I initialize it in `setup`

```
class Enemy1{
    constructor(number_of_enemies){
        this.number_of_enemies = number_of_enemies;
        this.enemy_position = [];
        this.generate_random_x = random(10, 100);

    }
    enemy1_spawn(){
        for(var i=0; i<this.number_of_enemies; i++){
            var positionx = this.generate_random_x;
            var positiony = 100;

            this.enemy_position.push([positionx, positiony]);
            image(enemy1, this.enemy_position[i][0], this.enemy_position[i][1]);
        }

    }

    enemy1_move(){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.enemy_position.length; i++)
        {
            this.enemy_position[i][0] += 2; //Move the enemy to the right
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried making separate functions(as before) and put my random inside `setup`, but nothing is displaying on the screen.

```
function enemy1_spawn(number_of_enemies){
    for(var i=0; i<number_of_enemies; i++){
        var positionx = gen_ran_x;
        var positiony = 100;

        enemy_position.push([positionx, positiony]);
        image(enemy1, enemy_position[i][0], enemy_position[i][1]);
    }

}

function enemy1_move(){
    for(var i = 0; i < enemy_position.length; i++)
    {
            image(enemy1, enemy_position[i][0], enemy_position[i][1]);
            enemy_position[i][0] += 2; //Move the enemy to the right
            // print(enemy_position[i][0], enemy_position[i][1]);
        }
      }
```

**My setup**

```
var generate_random_x;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 600);
    livesImg.resize(40, 40);
    enemy1_spawn(1);
    // classenemy1.enemy1_spawn();
    generate_random_x = random(10, 100);
```

---

### Updates 2

---

This is currently working, however I need a way to randomize my `positionx`

```
class Enemy1{
    constructor(number_of_enemies){
        this.number_of_enemies = number_of_enemies;
        this.enemy_position = [];

    }
    enemy1_spawn(){
        for(var i=0; i<this.number_of_enemies; i++){
            var positionx = 10;
            var positiony = 100;

            this.enemy_position.push([positionx + i*50, positiony]);
            image(enemy1, this.enemy_position[i][0], this.enemy_position[i][1]);
        }

    }

    enemy1_move(){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.enemy_position.length; i++)
        {
            image(enemy1, this.enemy_position[i][0], this.enemy_position[i][1]);
            this.enemy_position[i][0] += 2; //Move the enemy to the right
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are generating a new random position at every frame. To move the enemies, you have generate the position only once, and then update it.

For this, you can make a new function:

```
function ememy1_move(){
   for(var i = 0; i < enemy_position.length; i++)
   {
      enemy_position[i][0] += 2; //Move the enemy to the right
   }
}
```

Then, you only call `enemy1_spawn()` once in setup, and `enemy1_move()` in `draw()`.

Please also note that you forgot the `var` or `let` at the end of your `enemy1_spawn()` function:

```
for(j = 0
```

**Update:**
As you yourself pointed out, you can add

```
let randomx = random(-100, 0);
```

to your `enemy1_spawn()` function and set

```
positionx = randomx
```

Comment: I'm quite new to JavaScript could you show me the best method to generate a random position for as many enemies as the argument for ```enemy1_spawn```. I think I'm currently making the process much longer than it should be.

Comment: Well, instead of using an array of arrays (2D array), you could use an array of [p5.Vectors](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector). It also looks like you are not using you `var position` at all, so you could probably delete it. Other than that, I'm not sure what you mean. `var positionx = random(-100, 0)` doesn't seem bad. Or do you mean the commented out code?

Comment: I have updated my question with some more stuff that I have tried but it doesn't display anything on the screen. That random part is to generate the enemies outside the screen and then start bringing them from the left to right. I don't want them all to start from the same spot hence I'm using random

Comment: I understand, but I cannot reproduce the error. When adding the class to the `sketch.js` file, `var e = new Enemy1()` does not produce an exception. If you have your class in a seperate file, have you added a link to it in the `index.html` file? If you did, when do you know when _exactly_the error occurs?

Comment: My class is in the same file

Comment: Currently I'm using the functions and that doesn't give me any error, but there is still nothing on the screen. I figured out that my error has something to do with the random part. I tried putting a value for ```positionx``` in the function and it is working perfectly.

Comment: The problem is that your variable is called `generate_random_x`, but you try to use `gen_ran_x` in your `enemy1_spawn()` function.

Comment: I was storing the value of ```generate_random_x``` in ```gen_ran_x```. Please check out my updates 2

Comment: I figured out that I was not initialising my random variable properly. I have to add this-```let randomx = random(-100, 0);```. before my for loop in ```enemy1_spawn``` method and of course make ```positionx = randomx```. Please include this in your answer and I'll accept it.